# ping is working but update is not working on virtualbox guest

Tags: networking, server, apt, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu server 14.04.1 installed in VirtualBox. When the network adapter is set to bridged adapter I can `ping google.com` but `apt-get update` hangs on 
`0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13)] [Connecting to security`.
When it's set to NAT though it works just fine but i need public ip so I can access the system remotely so it needs to be bridged adapter so how do i make it work?

I had it working before but when I deleted the vm and started over it started acting like that and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Normally to use apt-get you don't need to assign public IPs. Also, Ping uses the ICMP protocol, which doesn't have a concept of ports, so it would normally works. But apt-get either uses HTTP or FTP connections, depending on how your /etc/apt/sources.list is configured. So you need to allow these ports to communicate to the repositories.